# The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is not working when the system has installed Kingsoft sheets while it works when has MS excel or WPS

Tags: c#, excel

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

gives error :

> {"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002).":null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel Interop is provided by Microsoft Office, Kingsheet does not provide it.
Upshoot: If possible, use some abstraction of excel worksheets whih works without Interop (which has other drawbacks, too), e.g. EPPLus.